# Using Ansible Playbook how to copy Java certs to hosts?

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible Playbook how to copy Java certs to hosts? Each host is having different JDK installed. I need to verify in all hosts which JDK is running and copy those certificate to all the hosts.

I have written the below playbook and the error that I'm getting. Please help me with figuring out what's wrong.

```
---
- hosts: test
  vars:
      pack1: /ngs/app/rdrt
      pack2: /usr/java/jdk*

  tasks:
    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/apple_corporate_root_ca.pem"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"
    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/apple_corporate_root_ca2.pem"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"
    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/ca-trust-check-1.0.0.jar"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"
    - name: Import SSL certificate to a given cacerts keystore
      java_cert:
         cert_path: "{{ pack1 }}/apple_corporate_root_ca.pem"
         cert_alias: Apple_Corporate_Root_CA
         cert_port: 443
         keystore_path: "{{ pack2 }}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
         keystore_pass: change-it
         executable: "{{ pack2 }}/bin/keytool"
         state: present
    - name: Import SSL certificate to a cacerts keystore
      java_cert:
         cert_path: "{{ pack1 }}/apple_corporate_root_ca2.pem"
         cert_alias: Apple_Corporate_Root_CA2
         cert_port: 443
         keystore_path: "{{ pack2 }}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
         keystore_pass: changeit
         executable: "{{ pack2 }}/bin/keytool"
         state: present
    - name: checking those files trusted or untrusted
      shell: "{{ pack2 }}/bin/java -jar {{ pack1 }}/ca-trust-check-1.0.0.jar"
```

The error:

```
fatal: [c5147061@rn2-radart-lapp117.rno.apple.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "'/usr/java/jdk*/bin/keytool'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
fatal: [c5147061@rn2-radart-lapp121.rno.apple.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "'/usr/java/jdk*/bin/keytool'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following error is displayed:

```
"cmd": "'/usr/java/jdk*/bin/keytool'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

As you can see, the `keytool` command can not be found in that location. You need to ensure that the path you're providing is actually there on the server.

Where you define the `pack2` variable, you need to provide the full path instead of using a wildcard, e.g. like this:

```
vars:
    pack2: /usr/java/jdk-1.8.0_67
```

Then ensure that this path exists on the remote machine, and your code should no longer show that error.

If the path is different on each node since you have a different version of Java on each node, here are some options:

- Use host-specific variables for defining the path for each host, if you have that information.
- Gather the information in a previous step, e.g. like here: [Check Java version via Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740372/check-java-version-via-ansible-playbook).
- Check the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to see if that is set.

Comment: No.in each host jdk version is different.some host may have jdk-1.8.0_67 and some hosts have jdk-1.8.8 like that.but jdk is there in each host.in that keytool is there.so we need to find out that.which jdk running according to that that location will take.

Comment: I've added some more options to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error that the keytool utility was not found (on my PATH), but that was because I did not use the become_user which has the correct PATH value.
So my solution was to add the following line to my playbook: 
  become: yes
  become_user: wls
(wls is the weblogic user but can be another system account depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because keytool was link to a really old version of the JDK (version 6).
By using a more recent version (JDK version 11), I fixed this error.